# HTML anchor tag does not work without http or https for external address

Tags: html, href

I have the following anchor tag.

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

When I click on the above link the URL will get **mydomain.com/www.google.com**
I have to say When I set href like the following

```
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

It works and goes to **google.com**

How can I have an anchor tag like this : `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: That's how it is supposed to behave. You can do <a href='//google.com'>google</a>

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the anchor tag `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` behaves as expected and navigates to the correct URL, you need to provide the complete URL including the protocol (e.g., "https://") in the `href` attribute.

If you omit the protocol, the browser will interpret the URL as a relative path instead of an absolute URL. In your case, `www.google.com` without a protocol will be treated as a relative path and appended to the current domain, resulting in `mydomain.com/www.google.com`

To achieve the desired behavior, you can modify the href attribute as follows:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `https://` in the beginning of an `href` attribute for anchor tags. That's how it works and that's what you should follow. But if you really want an alternative solution then you can try the cool trick that I have written with JavaScript.

```js
var all_a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(i=0; i < all_a.length; i++){
    all_a[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.setAttribute('href', 'http://' + this.getAttribute('href'));
    })
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```